# Any wordpress pluign for generating statistics graph in front end?

Tags: php, graph, wordpress

Does anybody know how to show website statistics ( view per day ) for a wordpress site in line graph format in front end. I searched for plugins and nothing suited properly. is their any code snippets? i desperate to bring that in my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tracking system provided by [GetClicky](http://getclicky.com) along with there [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/clicky/), this will generate all the stats you need both front & backend...

great little site for real time tracking, I'm prity sure its free, also unlike google analytics its up to the minute, showing current online users...

Comment: hello marty, the clicky plugin graph doesn't have a front-end, is their any tweak for achieving that?